# Storm - Kafka strange exception

Tags: apache-storm

On submitting a Storm topology, I am getting a strange error exception. Its running on one VM but is throwing exception on another. I could not understand why this is happening, so I am pasting the whole Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /brokers/topics/visit/partitions 
at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getBrokerInfo(DynamicBrokersReader.java:64) 
at storm.kafka.trident.ZkBrokerReader.<init>(ZkBrokerReader.java:25)
at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.makeBrokerReader(KafkaUtils.java:40)
at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.open(KafkaSpout.java:70) 
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4654$fn__4669.invoke(executor.clj:522) 
at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__458.invoke(util.clj:461) 
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:     org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /brokers/topics/visit/partitions at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getNumPartitions(DynamicBrokersReader.java:77) at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getBrokerInfo(DynamicBrokersReader.java:48) ... 7 more Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /brokers/topics/visit/partitions at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getChildren(ZooKeeper.java:1590) 

at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl$3.call(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:214) 
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl$3.call(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:203) 
at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:107) 
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:199) 
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.forPath(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:191)
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.forPath(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:38)
at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getNumPartitions(DynamicBrokersReader.java:74) ... 8 more
```

The logs from Zookeeper are :

```
3:16:19.497 PM  INFO    org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory    
Accepted socket connection from /10.67.33.201:37346
3:16:19.498 PM  INFO    org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer 
Client attempting to establish new session at /10.67.33.201:37346
3:16:19.501 PM  INFO    org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer 
Established session 0x44db46775060e2e with negotiated timeout 30000 for   client /10.67.33.201:37346
3:16:19.523 PM  INFO    org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory    
Accepted socket connection from /10.67.33.201:37350
3:16:19.524 PM  INFO    org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer 
Client attempting to establish new session at /10.67.33.201:37350
3:16:19.525 PM  INFO    org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer 
Established session 0x44db46775060e2f with negotiated timeout 30000 for   client /10.67.33.201:37350
3:16:19.591 PM  INFO    org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor    
Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x54db467a6bd0d0c
3:16:19.595 PM  INFO    org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor    
Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x14db46774a60d57
3:16:19.598 PM  INFO    org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor    
Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x44db46775060e2f
```

Since its running on one cluster and not on other, I am guessing it must be some cluster issue. 
It will be really great if one can point out the problem.

Comment: A few questions to move forward:  1. Can you reproduce this error while running locally with a single ZK and Supervisor?  2. Have you verified that the Kafka topic exists?  3. How many partitions does this Kafka topic have?